# How to get documents that got hit today in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In elasticsearch index, I want to get all documents that got accessed/hit today (or date range). Is there any way to get these desired results?

More Background:
The reason I want to get these documents is I need to check with `origin` source for any modification of these documents. If those are not latest/updated, then fetch the latest from `origin` source and update the document in the index.